# Using ListView, remove in Adapter always removes the last item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in my Activity with a custom Adapter.

Every item has a delete button on it. When someone clicks on the button, a dialog pops up asking if the user really wants to delete the item, upon clicking on yes, the item gets deleted.

I verified that internally the right items gets removed, but visually only the last item from the list gets removes. Activity.recreate shows that the right item got deleted, but I don't want to call recreate when a simple remove and notifyDataSetChanged() could do the trick.

Can someone point me into the right direction as to what could be wrong with my code?

the source code in my activity is:

```
        ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFriends);
        SS4ListItemFriendsAdapter adapter = new SS4ListItemFriendsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), SS4NewGameActivity.this, SS4ListItemFriendsRows);
          mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my Adapter:

```
public class SS4ListItemFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 Context context;
 List<SS4ListItemFriendsRow> rowItems;
 private Activity activity;


  SS4ListItemFriendsAdapter(Context context, Activity act, List<SS4ListItemFriendsRow> rowItems) {

  this.context = context;
  this.rowItems = rowItems;
  this.activity = act;

 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return rowItems.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return rowItems.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
 }

 /* private view holder class */
 private class ViewHolder {
  ImageView avatar;
  ImageView delete;
  TextView username;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder holder = null;

  LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ss4_list_item_friends, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.username = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.username);
   holder.avatar = (ImageView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.avatar);

   holder.delete = (ImageView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.delete);

   if (getCount() > 0) {       
       if (((SS4ListItemFriendsRow) getItem(0)).getDelete() == 0) {    
           holder.delete.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
       }
   }

   final SS4ListItemFriendsRow row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

   holder.avatar.setImageResource(row_pos.getAvatar());
   holder.username.setText(row_pos.getUsername());

   holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Sounds.buttonClick();
           Log.d(App.TAG, row_pos.getUsername());

           deleteFriendDialogBox(row_pos.getUsername(), position);             
       }
   });   

   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  return convertView;
 }

 private void deleteFriendDialogBox(final String username, final int position)
 {

    //String title = "deleteFriend?";
    String msg = context.getResources().getString(R.string.ss4_delete_friend);

     AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =  new AlertDialog.Builder(activity) 

         .setCancelable(false)
         .setTitle("")
         .setMessage(msg) 


         .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 

                    rowItems.remove(position); 
                    Log.d(App.TAG,"position: "+String.valueOf(position));

                    notifyDataSetChanged();                         
                    SS4NewGameActivity.getListViewSize(mylistview);                     

                    //activity.recreate();
                    try {
                        int showMsgBox = (Integer) friend.getInt("showMsgBox");
                        if (showMsgBox == 1) {
                            String msg = (String) friend.getString("msg");
                            Toast.makeText(context, msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }                   
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Sounds.buttonClick();

             }              
         })//setPositiveButton

         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Sounds.buttonClick();


          } 
         })//setNegativeButton

         .create();

     myQuittingDialogBox.show();
 }    

}
```

Comment: try to use invalidateViews() and refreshDrawableState() on listview, if notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged works, but removes the wrong item (always the last)

Comment: just tried invalidateViews() and refreshDrawableState() together with notifyDataSetChanged and without, still the same effect. the last item gets deleted everytime

Comment: I just updated your code. Can you verify and tell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated Code:- All the set on object need to be outside .. check updated code here.

```
public class SS4ListItemFriendsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 Context context;
 List<SS4ListItemFriendsRow> rowItems;
 private Activity activity;


  SS4ListItemFriendsAdapter(Context context, Activity act, List<SS4ListItemFriendsRow> rowItems) {

  this.context = context;
  this.rowItems = rowItems;
  this.activity = act;

 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return rowItems.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return rowItems.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
 }

 /* private view holder class */
 private class ViewHolder {
  ImageView avatar;
  ImageView delete;
  TextView username;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder holder = null;

  LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.ss4_list_item_friends, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.username = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.username);
   holder.avatar = (ImageView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.avatar);

   holder.delete = (ImageView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.delete);



   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }

   if (getCount() > 0) {       
       if (((SS4ListItemFriendsRow) getItem(0)).getDelete() == 0) {    
           holder.delete.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
       }
   }

   final SS4ListItemFriendsRow row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

   holder.avatar.setImageResource(row_pos.getAvatar());
   holder.username.setText(row_pos.getUsername());

   holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Sounds.buttonClick();
           Log.d(App.TAG, row_pos.getUsername());

           deleteFriendDialogBox(row_pos.getUsername(), position);             
       }
   });   

  return convertView;
 }

 private void deleteFriendDialogBox(final String username, final int position)
 {

    //String title = "deleteFriend?";
    String msg = context.getResources().getString(R.string.ss4_delete_friend);

     AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =  new AlertDialog.Builder(activity) 

         .setCancelable(false)
         .setTitle("")
         .setMessage(msg) 


         .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 

                    rowItems.remove(position); 
                    Log.d(App.TAG,"position: "+String.valueOf(position));

                    notifyDataSetChanged();                         
                    SS4NewGameActivity.getListViewSize(mylistview);                     

                    //activity.recreate();
                    try {
                        int showMsgBox = (Integer) friend.getInt("showMsgBox");
                        if (showMsgBox == 1) {
                            String msg = (String) friend.getString("msg");
                            Toast.makeText(context, msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }                   
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Sounds.buttonClick();

             }              
         })//setPositiveButton

         .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Sounds.buttonClick();


          } 
         })//setNegativeButton

         .create();

     myQuittingDialogBox.show();
 }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load the adapter again after calling notifyDatasetChange()

Answer (score 0):

As this is a model list, So, there is a method to remove list item with object:

```
list.remove(object);
```

We get the model object in Adapter as follows :

```
  final RequestModel p = getItem(position);
```

So, What I did that I passed the whole model object in onClick delete method, and delete the row :

```
 ll_cart_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (p.getProductImageLink() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(p.getProductImageLink())) {


                            chooseFillOptions(p, p.getProductImageLink(), finalProductNameString, position);
                        

                        }
                    }
                });
```

See that, the `p` is the whole model object in position. And the `p` is the `requestModel` object in below method. Then in the Method :

```
void chooseFillOptions(RequestModel requestModel, String imageUrl, String productName, int position) {

            System.out.println("Position: "+ position);
            String[] array = {"Remove Item", "Show Picture"};
            androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            builder.setTitle("Choose : ");
            builder.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   if (which == 0) {
                        CART_ARRAY_LIST.remove( requestModel);

                        try {
                            CART_ARRAY_LIST.notify();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {
                            CART_ARRAY_LIST.notifyAll();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                       cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                      



                }
            });

            androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
```